# Iptables does not drop connection

Tags: linux, iptables

I have this iptables config:

```
# sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION
-N DOCKER-USER
-N f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1701 -m policy --dir in --pol none -j DROP
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 500,4500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1701 -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1701 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p tcp -m geoip --source-country SK  -m tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o ppp+ -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.42.0/24 -d 192.168.42.0/24 -i ppp+ -o ppp+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.43.0/24 -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.43.0/24 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
```

I am trying to do a Geoip restrict (necessary modules are installed) with:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m geoip ! --src-cc SK -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

If source ip is not from SK => drop

I also tried to drop all incoming connections and allow only from SK:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m geoip --source-country SK  -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

...but doesn't work either. What would be a "good" config for me? I think the default -P INPUT ACCEPT is not the safest setting on this machine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an accept rule above your drop rule for port 22:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Since you've already accepted the traffic, iptables will ignore the later defined drop rule.

Try using -I to insert the rule at the top, rather than appending it to the bottom (-A):

`iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m geoip --source-country SK  -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`